# How to implement DocuSign for a marketplace app?

Tags: docusignapi

We are building a marketplace app similar to the Uber model. In this the service provider and end customers both register with the platform. Once they negotiate for a particular service with each other, they need to sign a contract before they can transfer any payment. This will be a docusign embedded signing request where the service providers terms and conditions will be uploaded as PDF and then signed by the end user.

Do we have a way in the API to get the document sent on behalf of the service providers to the end users? Do we need to be an ISV for this? We do not want to make any one login to docusign and want to application to work seamlessly.

Comment: Very simple: Use Rest API with single account, since you need to just get the contracts signed by customer and service providers, you can get it done via Rest API integrations. Need not to ask each customers to signup for DocuSign account. I have just finished freelancecentral.com platform where employer and contractors both sign the documents via DocuSign, there I have used DocuSign Rest API with single account. Docusign has all sorts of APIs like Embedded Sending, Embedded Signing and Hybrid Mode(Remote+ In App Signining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to automate the sending of agreements from the providers to the customers.

Since the providers are in different companies,  each provider company should have their own DocuSign account.

The providers could then use your app to automate the sends.

Or you can provide the DocuSign accounts (one per provider company)

Both options work fine. With the second option, you have a different status with DocuSign. ("ISV-L") rather than regular ISV.

If you feel that many of the providers already have a DocuSign account, then the first option may be better.

Contact partners.docusign.com for more information.

### Follow-up question (see comment)

> A follow up from the original poster: Will it be ok to just use a regular DocuSign account and then have the service provider agree to something like "We accept and authorize XYZ app to handle contract on behalf of our company"

I think you're suggesting that the providers would authorize your company to make legally binding contracts on behalf of the providers.

You're asking a contract law question. My answer (IANAL) is no. But your mileage may very. Consult your finance director or legal counsel for the answer that applies to you.

You could use DocuSign to send out a contract where the first party is the provider, and after they sign, the contract is sent to the end customer.

But that probably violates [DocuSign's terms and conditions](https://www.docusign.com/company/terms-and-conditions/web). Ask your lawyer before proceeding.

My suggestion is the first option listed above. Many of your providers may already have a DocuSign account, and others would be willing to purchase one to achieve the benefits of eSignatures and automatic contract generation via your app.

If you design your app correctly, it will be easy for your providers to install and use.

Comment: A followup on this: Will it be ok to just use a regular docusign account and then have the service provide agree to something like "We accept and authorize XYZ app to handle contract on behalf of our company"

Comment: @Prasanth -- see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Use Rest API with single account, since you need to just get the contracts signed by customer and service providers, you can get it done via Rest API integrations.

Need not to ask each customers to signup for DocuSign account and then have consent stored.

I have just finished https://www.freelancecentral.com platform this is market place for freelancers and employers, where employer and contractors both sign the documents via DocuSign, there I have used DocuSign Rest API with single account.

Docusign has all sorts of APIs like Embedded Sending, Embedded Signing and Hybrid Mode(Remote+ In App Signining)

However, client is using ISV licensing